# Null Pointer Exception after setText

Tags: android

I've encountered a problem after I set set my text in Android. Well the scenario goes like this:

I use putExtra from one of my classes then starts intent. on the Second class I declared a String variable which will catch the Extra the code is:

```
String playername = " ";
String emailaddress = " ";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gamepage);

    playername = getIntent().getStringExtra("pname");
    Log.v(TAG, "Player name set to : " + playername);
    emailaddress = getIntent().getStringExtra("eadd");
    Log.v(TAG, "Email set to : " + emailaddress);
    TextView playerName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerName);
        Log.v(TAG, "view fetched");
```

I used Logs to track the passing of data and it seems to work fine but after adding the part of `playerName.setText(playername);`

the problem now begins and error logs shows this:

```
 11-22 16:30:50.271: WARN/dalvikvm(4621): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{arc.android.memorygame/arc.android.memorygame.SetGameScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at arc.android.memorygame.SetGameScreen.onCreate(SetGameScreen.java:29)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-22 16:30:50.397: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4621):     ... 11 more
```

Is there's a problem with my code? why does it returns Null Pointer Exception?

Comment: Post code at line 29 in your SetGameScreen.java file

Comment: that would be playerName.setText(playername);

Comment: @KaHeL can you please past here full code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `playername` is `null` after this line:

```
playername = getIntent().getStringExtra("pname");
```

`getStringExtra` will return null if no string value is found.

Try something like this:

```
playername = getIntent().getStringExtra("pname");
if (playername == null)
    playername = "some default value";
```

Later edit:

If you are absolutely certain that `playername` is not `null` at that point, it means that `findViewById` returned `null` for some reason (a typo, an error in your `xml` or whatever).

And, by the way, if you have logs and can check for yourself if a variable is `null` or not, why don't you do it instead of asking? A `NullPointerException` is not that hard to track down, especially when you only have a few variables.

Comment: nope it's not null. I have logs so I can check whether it's null or not.

Comment: Hi, I think I should check your answer since you almost got it right haha! well the main reason for the error is the casing of the (TextView)findViewById(R.id.playerName); which should be (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PlayerName); well I wasn't aware that it is even case sensitive without being noticed or being red lined. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that line 29 of your `SetGameScreen` is the `playerName.setText(playername);` and you are certain that `getIntent().getStringExtra("pname");` returned a `String` and not `null` I would think that you get the `NullPointerException` is because `playerName` couldn't be found in your XML layout.

The method `findViewById()` returns null if no item with at matching ID could be found in the layout.

You should check that `gamepage.xml` really has a `TextView` with the attribute `android:id="@+id/playerName"`. (If it has, you can try changing playerName to something else and then try again.)

**Note:** Try posting your `gamepage.xml` here so we can check it for you.

Comment: my gamepage.xml were coded just fine, i think. I will add my xml code together with my question.

Comment: oh no, can't post it anymore on my question. Is there's a way I can show it the otherway around?

Comment: I already got the solution to this problem and it's just a case sensitive issue. see my comments at Gabriel Negut answer. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the `TextView playerName` is null?

Comment: if you are so sure, that TextView playerName is not null, then if you can please mail me, your project. I hope you added necessary Activities in your manifest.xml file as well.